# Facebook IFrames on Mobile?

Tags: facebook, mobile

Wondered whether it was possible for a Facebook Business IFrame page to appear on mobile versions of Facebook?

If not possible has anyone heard whether this feature will be introduced in the future?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean will Page Tabs be displayed on the mobile site / native apps, then the answer is sorry, no, that's not currently supported.